# VBA - Nested "With Statements" within "IF Statements"

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba, with-statement, user-defined-types

Language: VBA - MS Access

I am using User-Defined-Types (UDT) within my code.
I would like to be able determine which section of the UDT i'm loading data into based on a state variable.  My first attempt was to use "With" statements nested into an "IF" statement.  This doesn't work (I get a compiler error that says Else without if).  Is there a way to make this work? or another way of going about using a state variable to determine which section of the UDT i'm loading?

```
Type MyOtherType
    Name as String
    Age as Integer    
End Type

Type MyType
    aMyOtherType() as MyOtherType
    X as Integer
    Y as Integer
    Z as Integer  
End Type

Sub QuestionableCode()
Dim UDT(0 To 0) as MyType
Dim State as String
ReDim Preserve UDT(0).X(0 to 0) as MyOtherType
ReDim Preserve UDT(0).Y(0 to 0) as MyOtherType
ReDim Preserve UDT(0).Z(0 to 0) as MyOtherType

    State = "B"

    If State = "A" Then
        With UDT(0).X(0)
    ElseIf State = "B" Then
        With UDT(0).Y(0)
    Else 
        With UDT(0).Z(0)
    End If
            .Name = "George"
            .Age = 30
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should show your research, including your errors.

Comment: @jdv I don't understand that comment. _I get a compiler error that says Else without if_ is an acceptable way to describe an error imo. The only thing I miss is the line causing the error, but that's not always present with compile errors. The question is well-asked in my opinion.

Comment: Show, don't tell. See [ask]. There are reasons we like to see what you have tried, and what results you get. Do you really think a sentence fragment describing an  error message is clear enough? Because it is not.

Answer (score 2):

You can't work with `With` that way. The compiler doesn't allow this kind of conditionally nested code. Not with `With`, not with `For`, not with anything else.

You can, however, use a variable to determine which value you're going to use in your with:

```
Sub QuestionableCode()
    Dim UDT(0 To 0) as MyType
    Dim State as String
    ReDim Preserve UDT(0).X(0 to 0) as MyOtherType
    ReDim Preserve UDT(0).Y(0 to 0) as MyOtherType
    ReDim Preserve UDT(0).Z(0 to 0) as MyOtherType

    State = "B"
    Dim myWithVariable
    If State = "A" Then
        myWithVariable = UDT(0).X(0)
    ElseIf State = "B" Then
        myWithVariable = UDT(0).Y(0)
    Else 
        myWithVariable = UDT(0).Z(0)
    End If
    With myWithVariable 
        .Name = "George"
        .Age = 30
    End With
End Sub
```